# How can I solve the '6 books' puzzle with Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I've just seen this question on math.SE ([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/699211/6876)):

> Six different books (A,B,C,D,E,F) of identical size are stacked as in
>   the figure:
>
> [image]
>
> We know the following facts:
>
> 1. A and D are not touching.
> 2. E is between two books which are both vertical or both horizontal.
> 3. C touches exactly two books.
> 4. A and F touch.
> 5. E and F touch along their cover (long side)
>
> How many books have their positions known?

I thought I could solve this with Prolog:

```
% Those are the books:
book(a).
book(b).
book(c).
book(d).
book(e).
book(f).

% This is how 'touching' works:
touching(X,Y):- touching(Y,X). % touching is symmetric
touching(p1,p2).
touching(p2,p3).
touching(p3,p4).
touching(p3,p5).
touching(p3,p6).
touching(p4,p5).
touching(p5,p6).

% List all possible positions:
position(a):- p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6.
position(b):- p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6.
position(c):- p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6.
position(d):- p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6.
position(e):- p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6.
position(f):- p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6.

% Every position has one book
getBook(p1) :- a,b,c,d,e,f.
getBook(p2) :- a,b,c,d,e,f.
getBook(p3) :- a,b,c,d,e,f.
getBook(p4) :- a,b,c,d,e,f.
getBook(p5) :- a,b,c,d,e,f.
getBook(p6) :- a,b,c,d,e,f.

% Add your facts:
not(touching(position(a),position(d))).
position(e):- p5,p2.
% C touches exactly two books: eventually something like aggregate_all(count, touching(e,X), Count):-2.
position(c):- p2, p4,p6.
touching(position(a),position(f)).
touching(position(e),position(f)).
```

But when I try `position(a)` I get:

```
?- consult(books).
Warning: /home/moose/Downloads/LaTeX-examples/documents/Programmierparadigmen/scripts/prolog/books.pl:37:
    Clauses of position/1 are not together in the source-file
Warning: /home/moose/Downloads/LaTeX-examples/documents/Programmierparadigmen/scripts/prolog/books.pl:40:
    Clauses of touching/2 are not together in the source-file
% books compiled 0.00 sec, 32 clauses
true.

?- position(a).
ERROR: position/1: Undefined procedure: p1/0
   Exception: (7) p1 ?
```

- Question 1: Why do I get an exception and how do I fix it?
- Question 2: Is there a way to describe fact 3 in prolog that is closer to the text?
- Question 3: How can I print all combinations?

Comment: You haven't defined a `p1` fact. To solve the problem, you'll need to set up the program in a completely different way.

Comment: Could you please explain me how to approach this problem? I'm new to Prolog and currently I don't know another approach to solve this problem.

Comment: The exception is because you have no fact or predicate called `p1` with no arguments. You'll hit the same exception with `p2` through `p6`. `position(a) :- p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6.` attempts to query the `p1` etc all as predicates or facts, but they don't exist as such.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the crux. You need to find *permutations* of `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, labeled `[A,B,C,D,E,F]` using logical variables that meet certain constraints. The constraints are books touching and books being horizontally or vertically aligned. The facts we have are

```
vert(1).
vert(2).
vert(3).

horz(4).
horz(5).
horz(6).
```

and some relationships between books, viz.

```
touch(3, 4).
touch(3, 5).
touch(3, 6).

touch_long(1, 2).
touch_long(2, 3).
touch_long(4, 5).
touch_long(5, 6).

touching(X, Y) :-
    touch(X, Y) ; touch(Y, X); touching_long(X, Y).

touching_long(X, Y) :-
    touch_long(X, Y) ; touch_long(Y, X).
```

The brute-force way (sufficient for such a small problem) is to just generate the permutations and check the constraints. This is called the generate-and-test approach in Prolog programming.

```
% books(A, B, C, D, E, F) unifies its variables with the
% integers 1 through 6 to meet the constraints.
books(A, B, C, D, E, F) :-
    permutation([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [A, B, C, D, E, F]),

    % 1. A and D are not touching.
    \+ touching(A, D),

    % 2. E is between two books which are both vertical or both horizontal.
    % We can take a shortcut by exploiting the asymmetry in touch_long.
    touch_long(_, E),
    touch_long(E, _),

    % 3. C touches exactly two books. That means that the set of all books
    % touching C has cardinality 2.
    setof(X, touching(X, C), TouchingC),
    length(TouchingC, 2),

    % 4. A and F touch.
    touching(A, F),

    % 5. E and F touch along their cover (long side).
    touching_long(E, F).
```

You can now run `books(A,B,C,D,E,F)` to generate the valid permutations:

```
?- books(A,B,C,D,E,F).
A = 3,
B = 2,
C = 4,
D = 1,
E = 5,
F = 6 ;
A = 3,
B = 2,
C = 6,
D = 1,
E = 5,
F = 4
```

etc. Solving the original problem can be done by observing the output; writing a fully automatic solution to the original program is left as an exercise (it's a bit tedious).

Comment: What is `\+` in `\+ touching(A, D),`? From the context, I'd say it is something like `not`, but that would be a strange way to write "not".

Comment: @moose, it is "not" and it does look a little strange, but it is the prolog syntax. Some prologs (such as SWI Prolog) allow `not/1`.

Comment: @moose It's negation. I think it's supposed to represent a ⊢ ("provable") with a slashed though it.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: fixed a bug (rules about "E and F touch along their cover (long side)" used D instead of F).

Constraint programming solution using ECLiPSe CLP Prolog:

```
:- lib(gfd).

model(Books) :-
    [A, B, C, D, E, F] = Books,

    Books :: 1..6,
    alldifferent(Books),

    % A and D are not touching.
    abs(A - D) #\= 1, (A #= 3) => (D #< 4), (D #= 3) => (A #< 4),

    % E is between two books which are both vertical or both horizontal.
    E :: [2, 5],

    % C touches exactly two books.
    C :: [2, 4, 6],

    % A and F touch.
    (abs(A - F) #= 1) or (A #= 3 and F #> 4) or (F #= 3 and A #> 4),

    % E and F touch along their cover (long side)
    abs(E - F) #= 1, (E #> 3) => (F #> 3), (E #< 4) => (F #< 4).

find(Books) :-
    findall(Books, (model(Books), labeling(Books)), Sols),
    table(Books, Sols).
```

Run:

```
[eclipse]: find([A, B, C, D, E, F]).

A = A{[3 .. 6]}
B = B{[2, 4 .. 6]}
C = C{[2, 4, 6]}
D = 1
E = E{[2, 5]}
F = F{[3, 4, 6]}
```

So, only book D has known position - 1.

Comment: It constraints values of both sides to be equal. http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/gfd/index.html

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko How can it be made to print out all possible configurations?

Comment: @Maesumi `findall(Books, (model(Books), labeling(Books), writeln(Books)), Sols).`

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko  What is a recommended free windows program that will process the above file?

Comment: @Maesumi ECLiPSe CLP works on Windows. You can download it from http://eclipseclp.org/Distribution/6.1_181/i386_nt/